# player.playVideo is not a function

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I hope someone can help with this.

I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: player.playVideo is not a function

**To Reproduce:** Click **Run**, then the play image, do it repeatedly until the error message comes up.

How would that be fixed in the code?

So that error message doesn't come up.

Click **Run**, not update to text code: https://jsitor.com/fH5DO8ZU6L

```
const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
    const config = {};

    function show(el) {
        el.classList.remove("hide");
    }

    function hide(el) {
        el.classList.add("hide");
    }

    function hideAll(elements) {
        elements.forEach(hide);
    }

    function showCovers(playButton) {
        const cover = playButton.parentElement;
        cover.classList.add("active");
        show(cover);
    }

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        hideAll(config.containers);
        const cover = evt.currentTarget;
        showCovers(cover);
    }

    function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
        playButtons.forEach(function addEventHandler(playButton) {
            playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
        });
    }

    function init(selectors) {
        config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
        const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
        addClickToButtons(playButtons);
    }

    return {
        init
    };
}());
manageCover.init({
    container: ".container",
    playButton: ".thePlay"
});

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
    "use strict";

    let player = null;

    const tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    function shufflePlaylist(player) {
        player.setShuffle(true);
        player.playVideoAt(0);
        player.stopVideo();
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        player = event.target;
        player.setVolume(100);
        shufflePlaylist(player);
    }

    function addPlayer(video) {

        const playlist = "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g";

        const config = {
            height: 360,
            host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
            width: 640
        };
        config.playerVars = {
            autoplay: 0,
            cc_load_policy: 0,
            controls: 1,
            disablekb: 1,
            fs: 0,
            iv_load_policy: 3,
            loop: 1,
            playlist,
            rel: 0
        };
        config.events = {
            "onReady": onPlayerReady
        };
        player = new YT.Player(video, config);

    }

    function play() {
        player.playVideo();
    }
    return {
        addPlayer,
        play
    };
}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    const cover = document.querySelector(".playa");
    const wrapper = cover.parentElement;
    const frameContainer = wrapper.querySelector(".video");
    videoPlayer.addPlayer(frameContainer);
}

(function iife() {
    "use strict";

    function coverClickHandler() {
        videoPlayer.play();
    }

    const cover = document.querySelector(".playa");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

[image]

Comment: Video elements use `.play` not `.playVideo`?

Comment: That did not work, did it work for you?

Comment: The link worked for me on Firefox clicking run.

Comment: Try again here: https://jsitor.com/fH5DO8ZU6L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it by wrapping line 99 with a `if(player.playVideo)`

```
function play() {
  if (player.playVideo)
    player.playVideo();
}
```

Comment: Tried that and for me at least it didn't work. I even console logged the player to ensure that it was initialized and no good results.